# identify rows with not null values in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How to retrieve all rows having value in a status column (not null) group by ID column.

```
Id      Name    Status
1394    Test 1  Y
1394    Test 2  null    
1394    Test 3  null    
1395    Test 4  Y
1395    Test 5  Y
```

I wrote like `select * from table where status = 'Y'`. It brings me 3 records, how to add condition to bring in only last 2? the 1394 ID have other 2 records, which status is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is:

```
select * from mytable
where status = 'Y'
and id not in (select id from mytable where status is null)
```

Comment: Using 'not in' clauses while a 'simple way' is typically not well-performing....an outer-join to the collection of null-status Ids is preferred.

Comment: @jason this is easier to understand and unless the data volume is massive this will perform just fine. Often the optimiser will convert this to a join anyway, so performance can be the same as a coded join.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select groups where the status is *only* y, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        (t2.Status <> 'Y' or t2.status is null)
                 );
```

If you only want the ids, I would use `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(status) = 'Y' and max(status) = 'Y' and count(*) = count(status);
```

The last condition checks for no `NULL` values.

You could also write:

```
having min(status = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing query "where status = 'Y'" will bring you not null by definition.

If you are trying to get grouped results, a "GROUP BY id" clause will achieve this, which will also require putting id in the select explicitly instead of "*".

Example: `SELECT id, COUNT(id) from table where status = 'Y'`

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this correctly you want to bring in the ID for a grouping that never has a NULL status value:

I would use a subquery with a not-exist:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM mytable WHERE status IS NULL;
```

Then filter IDs that do not exist in that list:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM mytable WHERE status IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible solutions, because I am unclear on exactly what you want as output:

```
Select Id, Name, Status from table where status is not null;
```

results in 3 rows:

```
 Id      Name    Status
1394    Test 1    Y 
1395    Test 4    Y
1395    Test 5    Y


Select Id, count(*) as anAmt from table where status is not null group by Id;  
    /* only retrieves counts per Id */
```

results in 1 row for each Id:

```
Id         anAmt
1394         1
1395         2
```